# How to get number of pages in word or epub using textract package using nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, text-extraction

I already find a way to get total number of pages in pdf using pdf-parse

```js
  const pdfParse = require("pdf-parse");

  const data = await pdfParse(file);

  console.log(data.numpages)
```

But i need to get total pagenumber for word or epub using textract or any package to solve it.

```js
  const textract = require("textract");

  textract.fromBufferWithMime(file.mimetype, file.data, (error, text) => {
    return text;
  });
```

textract only give text not pagenumber